# Determinant - Elementary operations in Matrix Equation

Tags: determinant

Why that highlighted condition is true ? How can we prove it ? 
I have no idea about elementary operation in this specific way i.e matrix equation and also in row operation we have to do something different
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Elementary *column* operations on a matrix are equivalent to multiplying the matrix on the *right* by an elementary matrix.

Elementary *row* operations on a matrix are equivalent to multiplying the matrix on the *left* by an elementary matrix.

Comment: That's fine actually I didn't get it properly. but may I know that why only we have just applied elementary operations on B Matrix

Comment: @user560199, $(AB)E = A(BE)$.

Comment: Okay I got it . Thanks